# How to onclick empty qty for mobile woocommerce

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am developing eCommerce site with woocommerce, in my shop page i added a number field to enter quantity. now i want to empty field onclick, but as the common thing to grab the node is name, if i put this code:

```
$('[name=quantity]').on('click', function() {

$('[name=quantity]').val('');   

});
```

it removes the 1 number from all filed how can i emty the filed thats clicked only keeping others untouched?

here is the url for checking: http://tinyurl.com/oa93yj7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by following code:

```
$('[name=quantity]').on('click', function() {

    $(this).val(''); //on click clear the qty field  

});


$('[name=quantity]').on('blur', function() {

    if($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0)
    {
       $(this).val("1"); //set the value to 1 if user doesn't put any qty
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('[name=quantity]').on('click', function() {

$(this).val('');   

});
```

Comment: thanks it works!! just one q if he doesnt enter any number is it possible to display the 1 again?

Comment: Yes.. Take a look at "placeholder" for your HTML input field. If you want it with jquery you have to create a jsfiddle. So we can testing.

Comment: @DipannitaChoudhury Use place holder as a 1 in your input box, so that whenever user leave textbox without entering anything, will display 1 by default